# About the domain of the derivative

Tags: calculus, analysis, derivatives

Is the domain of the derivative $f'(x)$ of a function $f(x)$ conditioned by the function $f(x)$ itself?

I mean, take for example $f(x) = \ln(x)$ whose domain is $x > 0$.
We have $f'(x) = \frac{1}{x}$, whose natural domain is $\mathbb{R}\backslash\{0\}$.

Yet I don't "care" about the branch $x < 0$, for $f(x)$ is not defined over here.

So my question is: is $f'(x)$ a new function, or when dealing with its domain I have to take into account the informaton about the domain of $f(x)$?

Comment: Note that with a codomain of $\mathbb{C}$ we can have $f(x)=\ln(x)$ defined over the domain $\mathbb{R}\backslash\{0\}$.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Many of my students seem to come to my classes with the misconception that a formula *is* a function.  That is, if given the formula $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$, they assume that these are all of the data required in order to define the function $f$.  This is *not* correct.  Three data are required to define a function:

1. a domain $X$,
2. a codomain $Y$, and
3. a collection of ordered pairs $(x,y)$, where $x\in X$ and $y\in Y$ (this constitutes a mapping from the domain to the codomain).

If two functions have different domains, they are *not* the same function.

In the case of the derivative of a function, one possible definition is<sup>[1]</sup>

> **Definition:** Let $f : I \to \mathbb{R}$, where $I$ is an open interval.  The *derivative of $f$ at $a \in I$* is given by
> $$ \left. \frac{\mathrm{d}f}{\mathrm{d}x} \right|_{x=a}  = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(a+h) - f(a)}{h}, $$
> provided that this limit exists.  The *derivative function* is a function $f' : I'\to \mathbb{R}$, where $I'$  consists of those points $a\in I$ where $f'(a)$ exists.

The function $f'$ is *only* defined when the limit which defines the derivative is defined, and this limit *cannot* be defined where $f$ is not defined, since the difference quotient will not be defined if $f$ is not defined.  Therefore the domain of the derivative *must* be contained in the domain of the original function.

In the case of the logarithm, it is true that if $f(x) = \log(x)$, then
$$ f'(x) = \frac{1}{x}, $$
but this function $f'$ is *only* defined for $x > 0$ (i.e. for $x\in\operatorname{dom}(\log)$ such that the derivative of the logarithm exists).  That is,
$$ f' : (0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R} : x \mapsto \frac{1}{x}. $$
There is *another* function defined by the same formula (infinitely many functions, in fact), given by
$$ g : \mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\} \to \mathbb{R} : x \mapsto \frac{1}{x}. $$
Note that $g(x) = f'(x)$ whenever both are defined, but $g \ne f'$ as a function—these two functions are defined by the same formula, but they have different domains, so they cannot possibly be the same function.

---

[1] This is a somewhat restricted definition of the derivative, given to avoid complexities such as the derivative at a limit point of the domain which is not an interior point.

Answer (score 4):

Let $D$ be the domain of $f$, and $D'$ the domain of $f'$.

**Fact 1**

If $f$ is not defined for $x$ (i.e. $x \not \in D$), then its derivative is not defined for $x$. That is, $x \not\in D'$.

**Fact 2**

If $f$ is defined for $x$ (i.e. $x \in D$), but not its derivative (e.g. cuspid, angular point, the left and right derivatives are finite, but they differ), then $x \not\in D'$.

In conclusion:

$$D' \subseteq D.$$

Answer (score 3):

If you define $f:(0,\infty)\to\Bbb{R}$ as $f(x)=\log x$, then the derivative is the function $f’:(0,\infty)\to\Bbb{R}$, $f’(x)=\frac{1}{x}$.

Now, you make the reasonable observation that we can reasonably define $\gamma:\Bbb{R}\setminus\{0\}\to\Bbb{R}$, $\gamma(x):=\frac{1}{x}$, and obviously $\gamma|_{(0,\infty)}=f’$, i.e the restriction of $\gamma$ to the smaller domain coincides with the function $f’$ above which is the derivative of the function $f$ (which mind you has a specific domain as described above). Another fact is that there exist (infinitely many) functions $g:\Bbb{R}\setminus\{0\}\to\Bbb{R}$ which are differentiable and satisfy $g’=\gamma$. **HOWEVER**, this does not mean $g$ is equal to $f$, nor does it mean $g’=\gamma$ equals $f’$. These are respectively equal only when your restrict the domain of $g$ and $g’=\gamma$ from $\Bbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$ to the smaller set $(0,\infty)$.

---

So, while there exist larger domains of definition (in this case, so called *analytic extensions*) for $f$ and $f’$, they are not equal as functions because the domains are different. It’s just a definition.